# Label not changing in window - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have this code that I'm following from a video. This is a function that gets activated when a button is pressed. In some parts I want to erase the previous output in a label every time the button is pressed:

```
# Search customers
def search_customers():
    search_customers = Tk()
    search_customers.title("Search Customers")
    search_customers.geometry("1300x600")

    searched_label = Label(search_customers)
    searched_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    test = Label(search_customers)
    test.grid(row=3, column=0)

    def search_now():
        # searched_label = Label(search_customers)
        # searched_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

        selected = drop.get() # This is a Combobox
        if selected == 'Search By...':
            sql = ""
            test['text'] = 'You forgot to pick an option'
        elif selected == 'Last Name':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE last_name = %s"
        elif selected == 'Email Address':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = %s"
        elif selected == 'Customer ID':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE user_id = %s"

        searched = search_box.get()

        name = (searched, )
        result = my_cursor.execute(sql, name)
        if selected == "Search By...":
            result = ''
        else:
            result = my_cursor.fetchall()
        
            if not result:
                result = "Record Not Found"
                test['text'] = ''
                searched_label['text'] = result

            elif result:
                test['text'] = ''
                searched_label['text] = ''
                searched_label = Label(search_customers)
                for index, x in enumerate(result):
                    num = 0
                    index += 2
                    for y in x:
                        searched_label = Label(search_customers, text=y)
                        searched_label.grid(row=index, column=num)
                        num += 1
```

1. The thing is, every time the code reaches this statement: searched_label['text'] = '', it says: variable referenced before the assignment but that doesn't happen with test['text'] = '' even though both labels are created in the same scope.
2. The only way it worked was to create `searched_label` inside the `search_now()` (see the commented lines and let's pretend to uncomment them and comment the ones above).

With the lines uncommented inside search_now(), when it reaches this statement: if not result, it sets `searched_label['text'] = result` without a problem, but when it reaches the last `elif`, it doesn't set `searched_label['text'] = ''`, actually, let's say the code was run and it first reached the `if not result:` statement so when the button is press again and it reaches the last `elif` it doesn't erase the previous output with `searched_label['text] = ''`.

In this last `elif`, I tried `reached_label.grid_remove()` and creating the label again but the previous output still remains so it mixes with the new output.

Thanks in advance, I'm still learning and I hope my question is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the texts of Label widgets regularily, it pays to use the parameter `textvariable`. It takes a `StringVar()` object that can be changed by any function. As soon as the StringVar gets a new value, the label changes.

I do not see the whole of your program, but this is how it works in general:

```
def search_customers():
    search_customers = Tk()
    search_customers.title("Search Customers")
    search_customers.geometry("1300x600")

    global labeltext
    labeltext = StringVar() ## Initiate a string variable
    labeltext.set("This is the mutable text")

    searched_label = Label(search_customers,textvariable=labeltext)
    searched_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    test = Button(search_customers,text="Change it",command=change)
    test.grid(row=3, column=0)

def change():
    labeltext.set("This is a new text")
```

If the program gets more complicated, you might also consider defining the dialog box as a new class, iheriting from Frame. There, you can define methods that have access to all widgets and variables without the need of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you. Actually, need more information. I am using `match case` statements instead of `if/else`.

Code:

```
def search_now():
    searched_label = Label(search_customers)
    searched_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    selected = drop.get() # This is a Combobox
    match selected:
        case 'Search By...':
            sql = ""
            test['text'] = 'You forgot to pick an option'
        case 'Last Name':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE last_name = %s"
        case 'Email Address':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = %s"
        case 'Customer ID':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE user_id = %s"

    searched = search_box.get()

    name = (searched, )
    result = my_cursor.execute(sql, name)
    if selected == "Search By...":
        result = ''
    else:
        result = my_cursor.fetchall()
    
        if not result:
            result = "Record Not Found"
            #test['text'] = ''
            searched_label.config{text=result)

        elif result:
            #test['text'] = ''
            searched_label.config(text='')
            #searched_label = Label(text=search_customers)
            for index, x in enumerate(result):
                num = 0
                index += 2
                for y in x:
                    #searched_label = Label(search_customers, text=y)
                    searched_label.config(text=y)
```

Let me know if this work.